# Java -version and Current version are different on OSX

Tags: macos, java

I build a java application for school on my windows PC today. At the end of the day I tried to load it on my Macbook Pro laptop. So I could show it to the teacher.

When I run it on windows its perfectly fine, when I run it on mac my screen stays "gray". So the application is not usable because there is nothing in it.

I assumed it has something to do with java version but the only thing I could find was that my "current version" seemed different from java -version or javac - version.

When I go to the current version folder and I check the plist in

```
<string>Java for Mac OS X (1.6.0_65-b14-462)</string>
```

I see multiple values pointing to java 6

While java -version returns

```
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
```

What would be a solution to this?

Comment: For future users thinking to have the same thing. Make sure your setVisible is after setContentPane (in case of devving an app)